# How to use tracing in GDB

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, debian, remote-debugging

In the [documentation for gdb](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/gdb/gdb/gdb_11.html):

> The tracepoint facility is currently available only for remote
>   targets. See section Specifying a Debugging Target. In addition, your
>   remote target must know how to collect trace data. This functionality
>   is implemented in the remote stub; however, **none of the stubs
>   distributed with GDB support tracepoints as of this writing**.

Emphasis mine. Where can I get such a stub (for C/C++ code compiled with GCC on Debian x86 or x64)? Or how do I go about making one? The documentation on writing stubs only mentions implementing functions to communicate with the serial ports. Thanks!

Comment: you probably should reference the FSF gdb documentation when using gdb on linux, (It turns out that this particular portion has not changed) as apples gdb was forked "In a time long long ago".

Comment: Yep, I got the warning that it was unsupported from my `gdb` and went googling, that's what came up, but it definitely applies to the current `gdb`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about remotes but some targets in gdb now do support tracepoints
there is possibly a way to get at this using a 'normal' gdb info or show command, I could not find it.  in the output below tracepoints are supported due to the 'supported=1',
this may not be limited to the gdb stub, but also the kernel the stub is running on.

```
$ gdbserver/gdbserver :12345 ~/tests/test &
$ gdb -quiet
(gdb) file ~/tests/test
Reading symbols from /home/ratmice/tests/test...done.
(gdb) target remote :12345
Remote debugging using :12345
Remote debugging from host 127.0.0.1
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x00000035dd600b20 in _start () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Created trace state variable $trace_timestamp for target's variable 1.
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.13-2.x86_64
(gdb) interpreter-exec mi2 -trace-status
^done,supported="1",running="0",frames="0",frames-created="0",buffer-size="5242880",buffer-free="5242880",disconnected="0",circular="0"
```

Comment: Which version is this? I have `gdb` 7.0.1-debian and `gcc` version 4.4.5 on kernel 2.6.32-5. `tstart` gives me `Target does not support this command` running as per your example there with `gdbserver`. `interpreter-exec mi2 -trace-status` gives me `^error,msg="Undefined MI command: trace-status"`. Thanks!